# Could a chip revision change break binary compatibility by CMSIS?

Tags: arm, cortex-m, cmsis

Suppose the following situation:

- You develop something to a certain manufacturer's ARM based microcontroller.
- You are using CMSIS for interfacing the hardware (as recommendable on this architecture).
- The software is finalized, compiled into a binary, product is being shipped.
- Five years later when you wanted to issue a new batch of the product, and find that the binary doesn't work correctly on the then-current available revision of the microcontroller you were using.
- After recompiling with a fresh CMSIS provided for the micro, it works.

Could this situation happen? Did it ever happen?

Why this is important is that there are some areas where recompiling a binary might not be an acceptable solution.

As far as I see it seems like this scenario is a possibility as CMSIS contains interface code (it is not just a bunch of header files, at least as far as I see it isn't, I could be wrong), and ARM's recommendation about it seems to be just that the manufacturer should implement it and provide this interface to developers.

I couldn't so far find anything at either ARM manufacturer about whether and how binary compatibility is maintained across chip revisions (if applicable).

Comment: Yes it can certainly happen, not possible to predict where, what IP.  No reason to expect ARM nor the chip vendor to update CMSIS or any library for a legacy product, you have to own the code. CMSIS is a current fad dont necessarily expect it to be around in some number of years.  Header files are likely not going to work around a chip bug, more likely added code will be the result.

Comment: No reason to expect binary compatibility across chip revisions.  Since we cant predict why a chip has to be spun we cant predict how it affects the software that supports that chip.  Sometimes the spin is to avoid software having to change, but usually not if it can be fixed in software they do that, the spin is generally to cover things that cant or cant practically be solved in software.  Or could be because of yield as well.

Comment: Either ARM manufacturer, there are countless number of chip companies that use arms and some percentage of those use cortex-ms.  Without trying can list several major mcu manufactures that have products with ARM cortex-m IP in them, more digging would uncover others.  Then you get into application specific chips and you open up many more vendors.

Comment: @old_timer Huh? Did somebody delete your answer? (If it contained sensitive details, and you did it, OK... Anyway, I really hope that at least these few comments can stay up if nothing else)

Comment: CMSIS identifies a programming interface, not a hardware interface.  Code compatibility can be maintained, but not binary compatibility.

Comment: I deleted it sounds like you have plenty of experience dont need me rambling on about stuff...

Comment: I never heard of a chip manufacturer doing such sort of update in the product lifetime. When a microcontroller is released, there are usually some bug fixes leading to chip revision but this is usually minor, and usually happening in first months of production. A chip manufacturer will not update the cortex core after some years of production, it would lead to too much problems like yours and they will prefer do a new chip with different part number than a "revision" of the current part.